# How to make this design in flutter , shape of listview

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I have some data from API and I want to fetch data like this design, how to make it?

[image]

and how to custom `ListView` to view this shape
I got to try this but the shape of `ListView` is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to base your `Row()` alignment on the parity of the index of said Row().

One way to implement this is by using the `ListView.builder()` widget:

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _yourItemCount,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            List<Widget> children = [
              yourWidget()
            ];

            if (index % 2 != 0 && index != 0) {  
             // Checking the parity of the index
              children.add(yourWidget());
            }

            return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: children));
          }),
```

You can read more about it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html).

As to how to make the level widget design, you could use image assets, combined with a [`CustomPaint()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) widget (for the outside circle).

Comment: great , but his duplicate another circle , and count of list 3